# how to know an operating system support which types of file extension?

Tags: linux, windows, operating-systems

.exe file extension run on windows but not run on linux. dmg file extension run on mac os but not run on windows.
what criteria determine if a file will run or not?

now Google Fuchsia os is being developed.It is Written in‎ ‎C‎, ‎C++‎, ‎Dart‎, ‎Go‎, ‎Rust‎, ‎Python. Does it mean program written by C‎, ‎C++‎, ‎Dart‎, ‎Go‎, ‎Rust‎, ‎Python will run on google Fuchsia ? or it depends on other factor?

Comment: extension is just a convenient method of that, but it really does not determine whether a file is executable / runnable on a particular OS. DMG is only a reference to a type of disk image file (similar to ISO), but not an executable. Mac "programs" are actually .app extension, and those .app are actually folders with lots more files under it. So no, file extension does not determine whether a file will run or not. Usually a file is an executable if the OS understands what to do with the file (usually after the source code is compiled for that particular OS).

Comment: @Darius that is a good answer, why not make it be one, and delete from here.

Comment: @Hannu Mine was a bit of a shot in the dark and not exactly a complete answer. Hence why I was putting it as a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

There are three very different types of "executable" files:

### "Binary" files

"Binary" is an incorrect name, but the most commonly used. These typically have a `.exe` extension on Windows, and usually no extension on Unix/Linux (but you can sometimes see a `.bin`). These files contain code directly executable by the processor, will directly use operating system services (for instance to read/write files or display things to the user), and need to be in a specific format to let the operating system load and execute them. Therefore they are different for each operating system. They are typically written in C or C++. In practice you don't need to know...

### "Interpreted" files

The executable files are just "plain text" files (they can be created/edited with a simple text editor). To be executed they have to be loaded and interpreted by a program called an "interpreter" (this interpreter falls itself in the "binary" category above). You can have specific versions of the interpreter for each operating system, so you can run these files in any operating system for which there is an interpreter implementation. Typical languages: Python (`.py`), Perl (`.pl`), JavaScript (`.js`).

### "Bytecode" files

These files fall somewhere between the other two. Instead of creating a program for a specific machine type or operating system, a "binary" program is created for some hypothetical "virtual machine". To execute it you use another "binary" program that simulates/emulates that virtual machine on your operating system. Code written that way can run on any operating system for which an implementation of the virtual machine exists. A typical language using this is Java (`.jar`).

Although "interpreted" and "bytecode" files can in theory run everywhere, to be able to do so they must have been written with care - to not rely on some behavior/functionality that exists only on some specific operating system. Not all of them are perfectly operating-system agnostic.

Comment: Care to elaborate on file formats? e.g. binary and bytecode editable by hex-editor, interpreted files with normal text editor.

Comment: At that point I would not recommend to anyone who has to lookup this answer to "edit" a file with a hex editor. And even the *"plain text"* files are fraught with peril, I've seen many a Python script disfigured by Windows' `notepad`.

Comment: interpretation error on your behalf. The suggestion is about clarifying what the content of the files are, not a direct suggestion of actually DOING an edit.

Answer (score -1):

the extensions doesn't have a thing with whether the app will run on certain OS. 
For example on linux all executable files are in ELF format Executable and Linkable Format.

On linux you can get which type the file is with command: file NameOfapplication

Whether the app will run on certain OS have to do with the programming language in which it is written and whether is compiled for certain OS and it support libraries of that OS.

Some languages like python, Java are cross compatible as they are not languages that compile fully but compile into the bytecode which is then executed by the interpreter on the OS that have their interpreters installed.
Hope this helps a little